# Automatically shut down server on inactivity (SSH)?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a server hosted on [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). The server is built on the [Linux AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/), based on CentOS. It is dedicated to a client project, and I connect via SSH. Sometimes, I forget to shut down the server when unused, therefore generating unnecessary costs.

How do I make the server shut down automatically on inactivity, *for example* after 30 min without an SSH connection?

Naturally, I am looking for the simplest solution. A check every hour or so would also be OK, just something that works reliably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of January 2013 [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) provides an option to [Use Amazon CloudWatch to Detect and Shut Down Unused Amazon EC2 Instances](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/01/08/use-amazon-cloudwatch-to-detect-and-shut-down-unused-amazon-ec2-instances/), see the introductory blog post [Amazon CloudWatch - Alarm Actions](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/01/amazon-cloudwatch-alarm-actions.html) for details on this functionality:

> Today we are giving you the ability to **stop** or terminate **your EC2
>   instances when a CloudWatch alarm is triggered**. You can use this as a
>   failsafe (detect an abnormal condition and then act) or as part of
>   your application's processing logic (await an expected condition and
>   then act). *[emphasis mine]*

Your use case is listed in section *Failsafe Ideas* specifically:

> If you (or your developers) are forgetful, you can detect unused EC2
>   instances and shut them down. You could do this by detecting a very
>   low load average for an extended period of time. This type of failsafe
>   could be used to reduce your AWS bill by making sure that you are not
>   paying for resources you're not actually using.

As outlined, this depends on being able to heuristically detect the appropriate condition triggering the alarm and stopping the instance - you might take it to the next level by means of [Publishing Custom Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) to CloudWatch based on the logged in SSH user count, idle time or else and gain more control/precision for the desired detection and shutdown process in turn.

Comment: As a first experiment, I set up an alarm which shuts down the instance when NetworkIn (averaged over 5 minutes) is below 1000 bytes (per minute) for more than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

For a self-contained solution that doesn't require setting up other services, and doesn't depend on usage metrics, set this script to run on a schedule:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Shuts down the host on inactivity.
#
# Designed to be executed as root from a cron job.
# It will power off on the 2nd consecutive run without an active ssh session.
# That prevents an undesirable shutdown when the machine was just started, or on a brief disconnect.
#
# To enable, add this entry to /etc/crontab:
# */5 *   * * *   root    /home/ubuntu/dotfiles/bin/shutdown-if-inactive
#
set -o nounset -o errexit -o pipefail

MARKER_FILE="/tmp/ssh-inactivity-flag"

STATUS=$(netstat | grep ssh | grep ESTABLISHED &>/dev/null && echo active || echo inactive)

if [ "$STATUS" == "inactive" ]; then
  if [ -f "$MARKER_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Powering off due to ssh inactivity."
    poweroff  # See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/56711
  else
    # Create a marker file so that it will shut down if still inactive on the next time this script runs.
    touch "$MARKER_FILE"
  fi
else
  # Delete marker file if it exists
  rm --force "$MARKER_FILE"
fi
```

To run this script every 5 minutes, shutting down the instance after 10 minutes of inactivity, add this entry to `/etc/crontab`:

```
*/5 *   * * *   root    /home/ubuntu/bin/shutdown-if-inactive
```

Change `/home/ubuntu/bin` to the path where the script was saved.

This was tested on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 20.04. See [source](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/dotfiles/blob/4d0d8cc4df33504352c032978759a6bd730eb957/bin/shutdown-if-inactive).

This expands on @dmohr's answer.

Comment: THANK YOU! 

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.4 with some modifications:
• First I had to make the "shutdown-if-inactive"-File executable (chmod -x shutdown-if-inactive)
• I had to replace the command "poweroff" with "/sbin/poweroff"
• Also for non-english users - I had to change the word "ESTABLISHED" to "VERBUNDEN" (German version)
• I also added 'rm --force "$MARKER_FILE"' above "/sbin/poweroff", so after restarting, the computer turns off after 2 consecutive runs and not the first run, but don't know if I'm right with my logic on this point

Answer (score 6):

You could create a cron job script right on the instance itself that uses a command like

```
netstat | grep ssh | grep ESTABLISHED
```

and if no result is returned write that to file, then the cron tries again and if it returns no results again the script runs this.

```
/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you're looking for is to keep the server running while you're logged-in, and your session idle for less than `n` units of time, you can do so via a cron script which you mentioned, by monitoring the output of `w(1)` which reports `IDLE` time for logged-in user, which you can use.

Comment: `w` does indeed look interesting. To get the idle time in seconds for user `ec2-user`: `w -hs ec2-user | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\{2\}\)s .*/\1/'`

Comment: I think he wanted to shut down automatically if _nobody_ was logged in for a certain length of time?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm the only user.

Comment: @feklee If you aren't logged in, then "nobody is logged in" :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton So `w` would return nothing?

Comment: Right, if nobody is logged in, there's nothing to see from `w`; its output would be pretty much identical to `uptime`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you do realize there's a user named `nobody` ;-)

Comment: @abbe If `nobody` logs on, then it's time to format and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

I also have few EC2 instances that I only use once in a while. [Here's a systemd service](https://github.com/bokan/ec2-auto-shutdown/) I made that shuts down instance when there's no SSH activity for some time.

Comment: Seems interesting. Unfortunately the link is broken.